Python - VDI printscreen / LOGGED OFF
do you have an experience with making printscreen of whole screen on VDI which I am connected to via Remote Desktop COnnection, keeping session alive in background, but not logged in at that moment.
I wish to use Python solution.
I tried these Python solutions without success:

pyautogui
pygetwindow
mss
press Printscreen button to save screen directly into folder using GreenShot

It causes error if not active desktop is visible or makes screen shot which is only a black image.
It looks like graphical interface does not create layer with application in foreground and therefore there is nothing to be saved.
Any idea how to solve it? I would like to create automation making printscreen in case of error or some special situations.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am using scheduled robot on VDI running in background when I am not directly logged in. Therefore screen is not visible (created) and making printscreen is not possible as graphical interface is showing "nothing". But program is working , processing some application and I wish to create image of normally would be visible. May be it is not possible, but may be somebody already solved something like this. More clear now? :)
